# Use moment.js to change the timezone on a datetime stamp, without changing the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I am migrating event data from an old SQL database to a new Mongo database, using NodeJS. However, whoever set up the SQL database created all of the dates for the events, made the times in PST/PDT, but the database believes they are in UTC time.

For Example:
A date from the SQL database may be: `23-APR-10` which MomentJS shows as: `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z` when `21:00:00` is the PST time.

Is it possible to use pure JavaScript/MomentJS/NodeJS or a different npm module to change the timezone on the DateTime string without modifying the time (i.e. `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z` would become `2010-04-23T21:00:00-8:00`)?

PS. Even though the SQL database only shows DD-MMM-YY but returns a DateTime string when I query it.

Comment: Its not clear to me what mongodb returns as string and what you get from momentjs when that string is parsed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov the SQL database I am getting the data from returns `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z`, when I try to use momentjs to convert it to PST I get `2010-04-23T13:00:00-8:00`. However, I am trying to get: `2010-04-23T21:00:00-8:00` to put into my MongoDB.

Comment: If SQL database sends `2010-04-23` and you do `moment('2010-04-23')`, it will parse considering your local timezone. if you do `moment.utc('2010-04-23')` you will get it in UTC. I would recommend storing UTC in database always. Then in server you can convert it to any time

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov SQL Database sends `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z`, which is the PST time, but the database believes it's the utc time. I'm trying to fix the incorrect UTC by changing the timezone offset so I can save it to my database as (the correct) utc.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, my mistake for confusing you I should have said I was trying to save `2010-04-23T13:00:00Z` in my database in my earlier comment (as that is more accurate)

Comment: The Z at the end (without anything after it) means it is in UTC. Parsers will behave as being in timezone 00:00.  I am very confused about input and output lol

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Yes, the way the old database was set up, it was never intended to be used outside of one timezone, so even though the times are in PST the database believes it is in UTC. If the old database was properly set up I would receive: `2010-04-23T13:00:00Z`, however I instead receive: `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z`. For the new database, to make it timezone independent I need to take `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z` (the pst time in utc) and change it to `2010-04-23T13:00:00Z` (the utc time in utc), however I cannot find a way to accomplish that with momentjs.

Comment: PTC is UTC-9hours. So what you're saying is that due to this timezone mishap, the actual timestamps got 9 hours added to them when they got stored in the db, and you need them removed. Is that correct?

Comment: @anujPancholi, yes, I need to remove the extra hours. Also, for future reference I’m using PST (Pacific Standard Time) not PTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the line of inquiry in the question comments, it seems your problem is that due to the timezone mishap, the timestamps stored in the db are stored without the timezone offset, and since your desired timezone is PST (UTC-8hours), the timestamps are 8 hours ahead, for instance, what should have been `2010-04-23T13:00:00Z` has become `2010-04-23T21:00:00Z`.

So what needs to be done here is that the utc offset for your desired timezone needs to be obtained and added to the date.

The offset in your case is known (-8 hours). However, we can fetch the correct offset of *any* desired timezone from the `moment-timezone` library.

```
const moment_timezone = require('moment-timezone');

//a sample timestamp you're getting from your db
const myDateObj = new Date("2010-04-23T21:00:00Z");

//timezone for PST as understood by moment-timezone
const myMomentTimezone = "America/Los_Angeles";

//offset for your timezone in milliseconds
const myTimezoneOffset = moment_timezone.tz(myMomentTimezone).utcOffset()*60000;

//perfom the correction
const getCorrectedDateObj = (givenDateObj) => new Date(givenDateObj.valueOf() + myTimezoneOffset);

console.log(getCorrectedDateObj(myDateObj));
```

You may notice that we are actually changing the timestamp, because the given timestamp and the requried timestamp are, due to the nature of the error, essentially *different* timestamps. Moment-timezone is only being used here to fetch the offset, it's not used to "convert" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Anuj Pancholi's answer is correct, however; the old SQL database I'm using seems to have a lot of quirks, so I had to modify his answer to get my code working.

My Solution:

```
function getCorrectedDateObj(myDateObj){
  const timezoneOffset = momentTimeZone.tz(timezone).utcOffset() * 60000;
  const dt = new Date(myDateObj.valueOf() + timezoneOffset / 2);
  dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 12);
}
```